# Serverless and TypeORM database doesn't initialize

Tags: aws-lambda, typeorm, serverless

A project with Typescript, Serverless, TypeORM and AWSLambda
I have this code to initialize the db:
data-source.ts

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: “postgres”,
  host: “localhost”,
  port: 5432,
  username: “use”,
  password: “pass”,
  database: “dbname”,
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: [CarEntity],
  subscribers: [],
  migrations: [],
})

// * (see below)This code is in the initDB() function that I call in the create function.
AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    console.log(“DB Initialized”)
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(“Error: “, error))
```

the problem is that I can't wait for the initialize of the db so the db is not ready to use when it gets to the handler function:

```
export async function create(event, context) {
  //await initDB() If I discomment this, it works.
  return clientService.create()
}
```

If I put that await intiDB() that call the db initializer (*) it works

So, where should I initialize the db ?

The serverless.yml file:

```
service: aws-node-typescript # NOTE: update this with your service name
frameworkVersion: ‘3’
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
functions:
   create:
    handler: src/handler.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: ‘’
          method: ‘post’
   update:
    handler: src/handler.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: ‘’
          method: ‘put’
   get:
    handler: src/handler.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: ‘’
          method: ‘get’
plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
```

the error I get is:
“errorMessage”: “No metadata for \“CarEntity\” was found.“,

but, if I put the await intiDB in the create function I can create a new car and save it to the DB.

Comment: Hi, same here, did you find any clue ?

Comment: Hi, sorry no, we went in other direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can await the database connection in the application start lambda bootstraping

```
exports.handler = async (event: any, context: any) => {
    if(!AppDataSource.isInitialized)
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
    return serverlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
};
```

Also be certain that any modules you are importing aren't instantiating objects that use the database connection as the top level code in modules run before the lambda handler executes and will cause this error. This was my problem.